# Does the Deezer Logo has to be visible in every scrolling state (position fixed) or is it okay to place it just anywhere on the page?

Tags: deezer

On the [Deezer Logo Guideline Page](http://developers.deezer.com/guidelines/logo), it says "Each application using Deezer API/SDKs must have to include a clearly visible Deezer Logo.".

I am confused about the words "clearly visible", as it doesn't tell me if it has to be visible all the time, or if it's okay to place the logo in any place which is big enough and not hidden by default.

For example i could put the logo in a container which is fixed to a certain screen position and therefore is always visible, or i could put the logo in the page footer, which would be more user-friendly, especially on mobile devices with small displays.

How do I have to position the Deezer Logo in order to use it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just has to be visible when the user arrived on your page, no need to be visible all the time but the user has to know that he is using Deezer service

Comment: Thank you, do you have any official documents you could link to?